# Chrome web-store not displaying my extension in search result

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Yesterday I published my chrome extension to public with title and name as 'Bumpy'. But I couldn't able to find it in chrome web store when searched with same name.

Please let me know, if someone has faced the same issue and right approach to resolve it.

Comment: Don't worry about it. The chrome store simply hasn't indexed it yet. It should show up in another day or so. It usually takes some time for new extensions to show up - at least from my past experience.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It usually takes some time (more than a day or so from past experience) for the Chrome web store to index newly accepted extensions. Unless there's a specific outage, it should show up soon.

If you don't see start seeing it within in a few days of release you can [post an issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/chrome) and someone should help you out.

Answer (score 9):

When I published my extension to the Chrome Store on Friday February 26, 2016, it did not appear in searches until Thursday March 3, six days later. And then only after posting the issue at
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/contact/developer_support/

CWS Developer Support never explained the cause for the original problem, or how it was solved. They only replied they were working on it, and the item just appeared three days later.

FYI, they did explain that Chrome Web Store searches are based on the regular Google search. Therefore if your search term partially matches other extensions that have high page rank *outside* the CWS, your extension may be listed far below them, even when yours more specifically matches that search within the Store. Poor design, IMHO, since users searching for a specific need within the Store are likely to value a close match relatively higher than rank popularity vs. when searching the whole web universe.