# Why can't I find my new Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I recently published a Google Chrome extension on the Google Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mofoquotes/llgbcepdhpgncgifhngonfebjnclcebk

It's published successfully, even my friends can view it, but I, nor my friends, can find it when we search for it in the Web Store searchbar. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It most likely takes time before it shows up?

Comment: @Webbanditten I hope so, I just don't want to discover that I've made a mistake weeks later

Answer (score 1):

As @Webbanditten stated, it usually takes some time (more than a day or so) for the Chrome web store to index newly accepted extensions. Unless there's a specific outage, it should show up soon. You can check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873522/chrome-web-store-not-displaying-my-extension-in-search-result). If you don't see start seeing it within in a few days of release you can [post an issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/chrome) about this.